# email server redelivers emails on NFS remount

Tags: postfix, nfs, dovecot

I am running a postfix/dovecot on debian server with virtual clients on a NFS based maildir backend. My problem is that every once in a while the NFS connection is reset and my clients are receiving all their server stored emails all over again. I have instructed those that can to not keep a copy of the emails on the server, but some just dont want to do that. The NFS server is Debian based as well and I have no issues with other systems accessing the data. Everything was working with out issue until recently and there is only one administrator (me) with access to make changes to the systems. I am looking for ideas as I have run out, googling did not produce results to this type of error and my logs do not show anything to pinpoint the issue. I do not think it is network or time based, I use rsync daily to keep the nfs time and email server time as close to synced as possible. most of the time its less than 0.6s apart. The network does not seem to be congested as I am not loosing packets and even when its really busy there is only a 20ms max latency.

Thanks

My systems

NFS Server (standalone server)
Debian 7
dual 1Gbps ethernet in full duplex (bridged, iperf reports 3.8Gbps to my servers with an average latency of 2ms and a max of 20ms
Dual 4x Infiniband (currently use to connect backup storage server to main NFS, but will be for all internal server to server communications eventually)
10TB storage used to store VM information and provide a file share for the email server)

Email Server (run from a Xenserver virtual domain)
Debian 6
dual 1 Gbps ethernet (bonded in full duplex to same Cisco L3 switch as the NFS)
10GB storage

Xenserver (baremetal server hosting VM's, there are three in HA setup)
32GB ram
dual quad AMD Opteron
dual 120GB raid 1 (for Xenserver boot and local storage, ect)
dual 4x Infiniband (not working yet due to Xenserver not supporting Infiniband or the OFED stack)
quad 1Gbps ethernet with all 4 links to the same L3 Cisco switch as the NFS

Comment: It sounds like they are using `POP3`. `IMAP` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ntp` to keep the time in sync.  This should keep the time within milliseconds all the time.  You can peer the servers with or without an external time source.  If you use one of the local clocks, use `fudge` to change the statum to a value around 8.  If you use both, fudge them to different strata.

Use of rsync to keep timestamps synced, raises the question of whether you deliver to one server, and read from a different server.  Postfix should deliver to the same Maildir that your users access with Dovecot.  No copying should be required.  If you are copying, you risk overwriting deletions.  Maildir storage work well over NFS.  Other storage mechanisms may not work well if stored on NFS.

If you are using automount to mount the user's directories, it may unmount the directories while dovecot still has data cached.  It may be best just mount the NFS share.  Alternatively, you can increase the automount timeout.